# How can I implement zoom functionality in pdf in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a magazine app, in which iI wan't to add zoom functionality. How can I do this?

Comment: -1 No details what exactly you are doing (how do you display the pdf?), what the problem is and what you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Convert .pdf file into .png** and then either **load that .png file into ImageView or in WebView** and `apply zoom functionality.`